# Glassfish server.log filled with WS-TX service is not available

Tags: java, glassfish

My glassfish server.log is constantly being filled with

```
[#|2012-04-18T16:17:15.732+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.0.1|com.sun.xml.ws.wstx.wscoord|_ThreadID=20;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|WSTX-CLIENT-1001: WS-TX service is not available. Unable to flow a WS-Atomic Transaction Context for web service invocation of operation '{http://localhost/}checkSession' from current container|#]
```

None of my applications use this and it's quite annoying having to filter through it in the log file.

Does anyone know how to disable this in any way?

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is older but here is the response.

Add the following line to your **domain/config/logging.properties** file:

```
com.sun.xml.ws.wstx.wscoord.level=SEVERE
```

You can do this with any class log, just get the name class (`com.sun.xml.ws.wstx.wscoord` in this case) and add `.level=LOG_LEVEL` you want.